# Deleting Cloudwatch logs using boto3

Tags: python-3.6, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to delete **Cloudwatch** logs irrespective of the Log group.
Is there any method available with **boto3** using which I can search for a *pattern(keyword)* in the Log group name?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call [`describe_log_groups()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_groups) and do the filtering within your code.

The only filter available is the ability to specify a `logGroupNamePrefix`.